# What's the better way for a Windows form app to set the task scheduler to run some classes that have already include in this app? (.NET)

Tags: .net, vb.net, visual-studio, winforms, scheduled-tasks

It's a bit hard to mention all the things clearly in the title.

Here is my situation, I have a VB.Net Windows form application which has built a long time ago by other developers. Now I have to build a new feature to it. The current application needs the user to login first and does all the things by clicking and verifying. The new feature is to let the user schedule a time to do all the things automatically.

I have done the task scheduler part inside the current application for the user to set the time for executing the TASK. But for this TASK, my first thought was to create a console application that can have another .exe file for the task scheduler to execute. The console application references some of the relevant classes from the main application to run all the processes automatically. In the end, it will have two .exe appear in the folder when the user installs the application. One for the normal way to process the data (user). Another .exe is for the task scheduler to execute (automation).

I did and it worked fine. However, I think it's not a good way to do it because it shouldn't have two .exe files in one solution (right?). Also, the current way I used which I just imported the main project to the new console application as a reference to use the relevant classes and functions. I could make these classes as a class library (.dll) for both projects to use, but it still has two .exe files.

What would be the better way for this situation? Is the console application really necessary?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing wrong with having multiple application projects in one solution. You can have as many as you need to do the work required. That said, one application project should not reference another application project. The correct way is to extract the common functionality out into one or more library projects and then have each application project reference those.

This is why it's important to write your code is a well-structured, loosely-coupled manner in the first place. If you have that common code scattered about various forms then refactoring will be an absolute pain. If you have everything in types and members that obey the Single Responsibility Principle then refactoring will be simple.